# Is \bword\b and \<word\> equivalent in GREP and what usage of \<, \>?

Tags: grep, cpu-word, expression, boundary

Is `\bword\b` and `\<word\>` equivalent in GREP and what usage of `\<`, `\>` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning is the same. But \b is Perl and \< > is Unix.
[For more details](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that

- `\<` matches the empty string at the beginning of the word;
- `\>` matches the empty string at the end of the word;
- `\b` matches the empty string at *both* the beginning and the end of the word.

Well, I bet this is not news for you :) but this is the only difference so you can any of these operators. I would *vaguely suggest* that `\<` and `\>` are a bit more readable, but it is more a taste question than anything else.